# Java array manipulation, invert an int[][] array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to flip each col in this array to invert the image. However, when I run my code, I get a mirror image of the second half of the image, for some ridiculous reason, that I cannot figure out. Can someone please tell me why this only works half-way?

```
public void invert() { 
    int[][] tempArray= someArray;

    for(int row = 0; row < someArray.length; ++row)
    {
        int x = someArray[row].length - 1;
        for(int col = 0; col < someArray[i].length; ++col, --x)
        {
            tempArray[row][col] = someArray[row][x];
        }
    }
    someArray = tempArray;
}
```

someArray is an int[][] array defined elsewhere in my class of size 328x500 
int x is a counter variable to decrement through the columns backwards

Comment: Can you explain the role of variable x? Can you explain what you mean by filliping? please

Comment: Your are overriding old values. You have to swap values. Keep in mind arrays are references so you are working on the original data.

Comment: Are you trying to invert the color of the image or are you about to rotate/mirror it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are manipulating the same array.

Remember java `arrays` are reference types. So your `tempArray` and `someArray` is referring to the same array.

Now, let's say row 1 of your array is `{1,2,3}` and your output should be `{3,2,1}`.

But since it's the same array, during the first iteration, the array will become `{3,2,3}`. And in the third iteration you are reading the same array and trying to replace `3` in `col=2` with the `3` in `col=0`. So your result is `3,2,3`.

You should instead create a new array.

**replace:**

```
    int[][] tempArray= someArray;
```

with

```
    int[][] tempArray = new int[someArray.length][someArray[0].length];
    // If you have variable length column, you may want to intialize it inside the loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have reversed half of them, you have lost the original values in the first half, then the rest of the loop just copies those replaced values back into themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method:

```
public static int[] reversArray(int[] array){
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.ceil(array.length/2); i++){
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - (i+1)];
        array[array.length - (i+1)] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Then:

```
for(int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++{
  someArray[i] = reverseArray(someArray[i]);
}
reverseArray(someArray);
```